# Printing using ReportViewer - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

We are using ReportViewer 2015 in our ASP.NET Web application and using it with IE 11. When users (without admin permissions), try to print reports, they get the following error:
[image]

If i click, cancel on this error: then the following pop ups appear:

[image]

and then regardless we click yes or no, we get the following message:

[image]

Previously we were using Report Viewer 9 and this was all working fine but that version of Report Viewer does not render well in IE 11.

Also we are deploying RSClientPrint-x86.inf to all user's machine.

We have also temporary assigned users admin permissions to their machine and when the set up happens on their machine, we have copied the RSClientPrint assemblies and then distributed them but it does not work.

Also even once the assemblies are deployed, as soon as the admin permissions are taken away from the user, their printing stops working again.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you running SQL Server 2008, R2?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Just curious if, as a test, you provide a link directly to the redistributable .msi or .exe and the client the performs a download/save as and then run, would that make a difference on machines having issues.

Comment: client doesn't have admin permissions. so it never works

Answer (score 1):

First, to eliminate the obvious, have the user permissions been set correctly? Quick search yields a [link](http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/user-roles-and-permissions-in-ssrs/)

Second, reporting services use Windows authentication by default. Looks like you want to use forms authentication [like so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-custom-or-forms-authentication-on-the-report-server).

EDIT : So it looks like it is an Activex installation rights issue. For Activex installation without admin rights, on an admin command prompt type `ocsetup.exe AxInstallService` and enable it once done. You will have to configure it using GPMC. More details on that are [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc721964.aspx).

Comment: if it was a permission issue, they wouldn't have been able to see the report data. The issue here is about printing using the ActiveX control provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Edited my answer... this might need to be done on each client PC though...